# Pivot multiple combination - Dataframe - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I have an dataframe with multiple combination with their respective rankings as shown below:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+
| Combination1 | Combination2 | Combination3 | Rank |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+
| VAR1 : VAL11 | VAR2 : VAL21 | VAR3 : VAL31 |    1 |
| VAR1 : VAL12 | VAR4 : VAL41 | VAR2 : VAL22 |    2 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+
```

I have already split each column into two columns as below:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| Comb_Col1 | Comb_Val1 | Comb_Col2 | Comb_Val2 | Comb_Col3 | Comb_Val3 | Rank  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| VAR1      | VAL11     | VAR2      | VAL21     | VAR3      | VAL31     |     1 |
| VAR1      | VAL12     | VAR4      | VAL41     | VAR2      | VAL22     |     2 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

What I am trying to achieve is (in pivot) :

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Rank | VAR1  | VAR2  | VAR3  | VAR4  |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    1 | VAL11 | VAL21 | VAL31 | NaN   |
|    2 | VAL12 | VAL22 | NaN   | VAL41 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**There are multiple variables, each with multiple values. What I am trying is to stamp all the variable name in columns and their values in rows respectively. If not, leave them blank or Null.**

I tried using below codes (but not able to achieve desired output):

```
(df.set_index('Rank')
 .groupby(level='Rank')
 .apply(lambda g: g.apply(pd.value_counts))
 .unstack(level=1)
 .fillna(0))
```

```
(df.set_index('Rank').stack()
 .groupby(level=[0,1])
 .value_counts()
 .unstack(level=[1,2])
 .fillna(0)
 .sort_index(axis=1))
```

```
df_out = pd.wide_to_long(df, ['Comb_Col', 'Comb_Val'], 'Rank', 'No').reset_index()\
           .pivot('Rank', 'Comb_Col', 'Comb_Val')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried separating the columns and values along with the rank, renamed them and then union-ed it.

```
+-----------+-----------+-------+    +-----------+-----------+-------+
| Comb_Col1 | Comb_Val1 | Rank  |    | Comb_Col1 | Comb_Val1 | Rank  |
+-----------+-----------+-------+    +-----------+-----------+-------+
| VAR1      | VAL11     |     1 |    | VAR3      | VAL31     |     1 |
| VAR1      | VAL12     |     2 |    | VAR2      | VAL22     |     2 |
+-----------+-----------+-------+    +-----------+-----------+-------+

+-----------+-----------+-------+
| Comb_Col1 | Comb_Val1 | Rank  |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
| VAR2      | VAL21     |     1 |
| VAR4      | VAL41     |     2 |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

After that, simple pivot query worked!

```
df.pivot(index = Rank,
  columns ='Comb_Col1',
  values = ['Comb_Val1']
  )
```